# How to set types of parameters in Azure ARM templates when using KeyVault references?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have an issue with parameters types when I reference them as `KeyVault` secrets. I need to include `Int`, `Bool` or `Object` types not just a `String`.

Here is my example, main file:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "userLogin": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "userPassword": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "numberOfCores": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 2
        },
        "subnetsConfig": {
            "type": "object"
        },
...
}
```

and parameters file:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "userLogin": {
            "reference": {
                "keyVault": {
                    "id": "MY KV RESOURCE ID"
                },
                "secretName": "MY SECRET NAME1"
            }
        },
        "userPassword": {
            "reference": {
                "keyVault": {
                    "id": "MY KV RESOURCE ID"
                },
                "secretName": "MY SECRET NAME2"
            }
        },
        "numberOfCores": {
            "reference": {
                "keyVault": {
                    "id": "MY KV RESOURCE ID"
                },
                "secretName": "MY SECRET NAME3"
            }
        },
        "subnetsConfig": {
            "reference": {
                "keyVault": {
                    "id": "MY KV RESOURCE ID"
                },
                "secretName": "MY SECRET NAME4"
            }
        },
...
}
```

I got that error:

```
Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Integer'. Actual 'String'
```

I cannot find a way how to make it work. Is that supported in that case?

Comment: The problem is that you're using keyvault to store non-secret data. Number of cores is **not** a secret and is inappropriate for keyvault. If you want centralized, Azure-based app setting management use Azure App Configuration.

Comment: This is an easiest example. I have different secrets in my keyvault and I need some of them to be non-string types in ARM template. The key question here is if we can use non string parameters in an ARM template. If so, then how?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of [int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric?tabs=json#int) you can convert it

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "stringToConvert": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "4"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "intResult": {
      "type": "int",
      "value": "[int(parameters('stringToConvert'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

and the same with [bool](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical?tabs=json#bool)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "trueString": {
      "type": "bool",
      "value": "[bool('true')]",
    },
    "falseString": {
      "type": "bool",
      "value": "[bool('false')]"
    },
    "trueInt": {
      "type": "bool",
      "value": "[bool(1)]"
    },
    "falseInt": {
      "type": "bool",
      "value": "[bool(0)]"
    }
  }
}
```

and you can also [create an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-object?tabs=json#createobject)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "newObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[createObject('intProp', 1, 'stringProp', 'abc', 'boolProp', true(), 'arrayProp', createArray('a', 'b', 'c'), 'objectProp', createObject('key1', 'value1'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `outputs` is accessible in `resources` during deployment. I use these parameters in `resources`. What do you think @Krzysztof.Madej?